# html page loading message

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html page loads a bit slowly because of the jquery that's in it. I want an image that tells the user that it's loading, until the entire page get loaded. How should I go about doing this?
Many thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      //my jquery here....

   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Design the page with the loading message already included so that when the page loads from the server, the message is already showing.

Then, using jQuery, you can hide the message as soon as the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadingMessage').hide();
});
```

Comment: this will only let the message show until the DOM is loaded, if the intention is to show the message until all the images are loaded, it's better my option: window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/m4Bxe/

```
window.onload = function () {

$("#loading").hide();    

   };
```

window.onload will wait the whole loading of the page. `ready()` waits the DOM to be ready which is practically inmediate.

You can read this in [these jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> "While JavaScript provides the load
>   event for executing code when a page
>   is rendered, this event does not get
>   triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received.
>   In most cases, the script can be run
>   as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been
>   fully constructed. The handler passed
>   to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready,"

Answer (score 1):

Justin's method will do the trick.

make sure you are optimizing the way resources are loaded, for example putting your scripts at the bottom of the page so they don't block HTML rendering

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you can load an image that says "loading", then load the rest of the document's scripts by either doing something like:

```
var TM_script = document.createElement('script');TM_script.src = 'http://www.yoursite.com/script.js';document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(TM_script); someFunctionInScript();
```

Alternatively, you can just load the image, and then submit Ajax requests to load the rest of the page. You can also try even doing an animated gif or another image at the top of the page, and once the document has loaded (and your script activates), remove that image.

Answer (score 0):

have a background-image set through css to the body, and remove the element in document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I know this a fairly old thread, but the below solution worked for me although jQuery is needed:

First right after the body tag add this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then add the style class for the div and image to your css:

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

And finally add this javascript to your page (preferably at the end of your page, before closing body tag of course):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loading').hide();   }); 
</script>
```

Then adjust the position of the loading image and the background color of the loading div via the style class.

This is it, works just fine. But of course you have to have an ajax-loader.gif somewhere.

Try [AJAXLoad](http://www.ajaxload.info/) They have some great animated GIF's there.. :)